# Class library referenced by multiple websites + version control branching

Tags: version-control, tfs, architecture

Consider the following -

I have a solution that consists of multiple projects:

- DAL (Class Library)
- BusinessLogic (Class Library)
- Website1 (Web Application)
- Website2 (Web Application)

Both Website1 and Website2 share a reference to BusinessLogic, which in turn references the DAL.

Since these are just websites, I don't need to keep track of multiple versions, as such, but I do like to have the following branches:

- Trunk
- Production

Trunk is where I do all my development work, and after everything is tested and ready to go, I merge from Trunk to Production when a website is actually deployed to production servers. This allows me to shelve my current work, check out the Production branch and address any major bugs that were found after deployment and immediately deploy the fix.

My problem is that, using this approach, what lives in the Production branch isn't always correct. Let's say I make an update to BusinessLogic which is utilised by Website1. It passes testing and is deployed. If I merge all the projects to the Production branch, then it's wrong because Website2 wasn't deployed to production at that time.

Or, I could merge only the relevant projects to Production. So, in this case, I would merge Website1, BusinessLogic and DAL. This is still wrong, however. If I were to check out the Production branch to do work on Website2, it would have a newer version of BusinessLogic and DAL than actually exist on our production servers.

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a lot of correct ways, and it always depends on what is correct for you. Each way would have pros and cons, of course.

If you'd like source-level dependencies, create several production branches per site, each includes external:

- /Site1/Production

  - site content
  - BusinessLogic [external]  -> /BusinessLogic/v1Branch
- /Site2/Production

  - site content
  - BusinessLogic [external]  -> /BusinessLogic/v1Branch
- /BusinessLogic/v1Branch (from DevBranch)
- /BusinessLogic/DevBranch

Here is how you perform version upgrade:

- Make a change to `BusinessLogic/DevBranch`, test it.
- Branch it as `BusinessLogic/v2Branch`
- Update `Site2/Production`'s external to point to `BusinessLogic/v2Branch`
- Build site2, test and deploy.

So you'll have -

- /Site1/Production

  - site content
  - BusinessLogic [external]  -> /BusinessLogic/v1Branch
- **/Site2/Production**

  - site content
  - BusinessLogic [external]  -> **/BusinessLogic/v2Branch**
- /BusinessLogic/v1Branch (from DevBranch)
- **/BusinessLogic/v2Branch** (from DevBranch)
- /BusinessLogic/DevBranch

This requires a certain level of development culture and some amount of svn management.

Also you can also put binaries to such svn branches, which is pretty much the same scheme. In general such approach is named [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

---

If you prefer binary dependencies outside the source control, you could utilize local nuget repository. It works the same as official one: you create a new version, publish to nuget, then refer it from site, the build and deploy. This requires additional setup and maintenance effort and is more appropriate for larger projects.

Comment: Using branching to solve this issue is dysfunctional and will result in long term reduction in code quality and major rework.

Comment: @MrHinsh "This requires a certain level of development culture and some amount of svn management." if you'd read it carefully. Of course it will. But in general code quality depends on coder. Some can spoil even parachute of golden code. I do not see really any issues in using read-only vendor branch. Besides, technically it is just the same code in the other form. As you may also noted, I propose binary distribution via nuget as well. It brings the same amount of problems as non-binary, the problems themselves differ. It's just old source-vs-binary holy war, if you'd like.

Comment: Code sharing is never the correct way to solve this problem. You are ending up with multiple different dll's containing the same compiled code. This is wrong and should never be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a code sharing or code promotion model. It reduces quality and forces rework. Instead look to create a release pipeline where you create a package for your Business and Dal layers and consume those packaged in the web apps.

The best approach for this is to use a build server and create a NuGet package for your DAL that is consumed by the Business Layer. This in turn is packaged as a NuGet package that your websites can consume.

Your workflow for getting a change to the business layer into your website is then:

1. Open Business Layer solution and make fix
2. Check in and trigger CI build
3. CI build creates and publishes NuGet package
4. Open Website solution and update NuGet package

Clean and simple. No branching is good branching.